# AudioSession - want to stop everything being played in background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I got a need to stop (or mute at least) music/sound that is played in iPhone.
Important: I want my app will do that it even if is in background-state!

I'm using:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:nil]];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES];
```

The issue is that everything is being stopped, even streaming music from some other app, but only if app is in FOREGROUND. As wrote before, I want it to be working also in BACKGROUND.

I did simple research and realized it's somehow possible, these apps prove:

[App Store - Streaming Music Timer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/streaming-music-timer/id394626194?mt=8) or
[App Store - Music Sleep Timer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/music-sleep-timer/id320583424?mt=8)

I guess my solution with SoloAmbient can be not so perfect and it may be a wrong way. 
Does anybody know how could I stop/sleep/pause/mute global music even if app will be in background state?
These apps I pointed out are doing basically this thing...

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the audio background mode.

Add the `Required Background Modes` key to your app's Info.plist and add the `App Plays Audio` key to it.

See [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/) for more.

**EDIT** Also, you probably want the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` category, not `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`

Comment: No no... I need my app stopping each possible music when this app is in background state (or in lock state). This way you gave me is not working so.